# Titan: Know if a new vertex or edge was created

Tags: titan

Does titan provide RDBMS trigger kind of thing that will be triggered whenever a new vertex or edge is added to the graph?

How will I know that a new vertex or edge was added to the graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Titan does not have a way to deal with that natively.  You could, however, use `EventGraph` which is a graph wrapper over blueprints:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Event-Implementation

`EvenGraph` will pop off events to a listener that you write to gather the events.

EDIT: The above answer applies to TinkerPop 2.x and Titan 0.5.x and earlier. In Titan 1.x and TinkerPop 3.x one would rely on [EventStrategy](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_eventstrategy) or Titan's [Transaction Log](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/log.html).

Comment: `Vertex v = graph.addVertex(100);` here if instead of `EventGraph graph` if i use `TitanGraph graph` event is not fired. and in my project every where i am using `TitanGraph`. So i will have to replace `TitanGraph` with `EventGraph`??

Comment: I was trying to implement transaction as here https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Multi-Threaded-Transactions#wiki-nested-transactions with `EventGraph` `EventTransactionalGraph et = new EventTransactionalGraph(titanGraph.newTransaction());Vertex v1 = eventGraph.addVertex(null);v1.setProperty("testProps1", "testProps1 value");et.commit();titanGraph.commit().` It throws `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported threaded transaction graph. Call on parent graph`

Comment: Yes...if you want events raised for graph mutations then you have to use EventGraph wrapping your TitanGraph wherever you use it to perform mutations.  Multithreaded transactions via `newTransaction()` has a bug that prevents the returned graph instance from being utilized with a wrapper: https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/592

Comment: Yah I had raised this issue before you..so cos of this issue will it be a good idea that i will use both `Eventgraph` and `TitanGraph` in my project?? When i will need event after adding new vertex I will use `EventGraph`. When I will have to add new user with unique username I will use `TitanGraph` cos its time consuming process and its support `newTransaction()`. I think for the use case of adding new post, new comment `EvenGraph` will be good enough cos here i dont need to have anything unique as username so dont need `newTransaction()` right??

Comment: You don't need `newTransaction()` because it is a "time consuming" task.  You use `newTransaction()` if your code is creating multiple threads to operate on the same transaction.  If you are not doing that, then there is no need to do `newTransaction()`.  If you are saying that creating a user is time consuming so you spin up a single thread to create the the user in the background, you still don't need `newTransaction` as no other thread is mutating the graph in that transaction.  Hope that clarifies things for you.

Comment: this is just for my knowledge,can we use both `Eventgraph` and `TitanGraph` in my project??Will there be any conflict?

Comment: I don't think so.  `EventGraph` is just a wrapper for Blueprints implementations.  You just need to keep track of your definition of `g` so that you get the results you expect.  I think that's the biggest danger of mixing them in that if you refer to `g` and think its a reference to `EventGraph`, but it is really a reference to `TitanGraph` then you will not see events generated.  That's really the danger of all wrappers.

Comment: ok got it... means we can use both if we keep track of which `g` we are using.